# mongodb explain always returns millis as 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the node.js mongodb native driver and I have a collection with a bunch of docs inside like:

```
{
    name: "cat",
}
```

I have a query which I am trying to test the speed of:

```
collection.find({name: { $gt: 'ca', $lt: 'cb' } }).explain(function(err, docs){
    console.log( docs );
});
```

But the milliseconds is always 0

```
 { cursor: 'BasicCursor',
  isMultiKey: false,
  n: 2,
  nscannedObjects: 8,
  nscanned: 8,
  nscannedObjectsAllPlans: 8,
  nscannedAllPlans: 8,
  scanAndOrder: false,
  indexOnly: false,
  nYields: 0,
  nChunkSkips: 0,
  millis: 0,
  allPlans: 
   [ { cursor: 'BasicCursor',
       isMultiKey: false,
       n: 2,
       nscannedObjects: 8,
       nscanned: 8,
       scanAndOrder: false,
       indexOnly: false,
       nChunkSkips: 0 } ],
  server: 'h003723.mongolab.com:33453',
  filterSet: false,
  stats: 
   { type: 'COLLSCAN',
     works: 10,
     yields: 0,
     unyields: 0,
     invalidates: 0,
     advanced: 2,
     needTime: 7,
     needFetch: 0,
     isEOF: 1,
     docsTested: 8,
     children: [] } }
```

I cant seem to figure this out, and obviously I cant test the query like this, am I missing something?

Comment: The output shows you only have 8 docs in your collection, so just about any query you could come up with with will be very quick, even w/o an index.

Comment: The millis is the time of the query, in this case the explain(), not the quey you are explaining

Comment: As @JohnnyHK noticed, you just fast :)

Comment: Because of what Sammaye said, you should ignore `millis` in an explain. The most useful fields in explain are `cursor`, `n`, `nscanned`, `nscannedObjects`, and `scanAndOrder`.